# On change event inside hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two AJAX functions. First function takes the result of the first input field and concatenates a string and then changes the value of the second input field. The second input field is `(type=”hidden”)`. Second function checks if there was a change triggered in the second input field and then display the value on the third input field. Nothing is being triggered by the change of value made in input field # 2. [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/concatenate/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = null;
    var $result=$("#result");
     $result.data('url',$result.val());

    function submitForm( input ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/concatenate/index.php",
            data: {input:input},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                var url=$result.data('url'),
                newUrl= url+input+'/';
                $result.val(newUrl);
            }
        });
        return false
    }

    $("#input").on("keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this).val();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
             submitForm(input) ;
        }, 40);
    })
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = null;
    var $result=$("#result").val();

    function submitForm( input ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/concatenate/index.php",
            data: {input:input},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $result.val();
            }
        });
        return false
    }

    $("#result").on("change", function() {
        var input = $(this).val();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
             submitForm(input) ;
        }, 40);
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Enter a word:</h1>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Input: <input type="text" id="input" name="input"></br>
Concatenated Result1(hidden): <input type="hidden" style="width:200px;" id="result" name="result" value="http//www.example.com/"></br>
Concatenated Result2: <input type="text" id="result2" name="result2" value=""></br>
</form>
```

Comment: There isn't really a need to wrap your scripts in two separate DOM ready events &mash; one is enough :)

Comment: @Terry, can you show me how? I tried but it did not work for me

Comment: Why 2 ajax calls?  It looks like the first one does nothing with the response `data`.  Could that just be a function without the Ajax call.  Maybe a little more clarification about what you're trying to accomplish would help.  The issue with putting all that in one onload is that you're using `submitForm` in both.  So if you put them all in one onload, you'll need to change your function names.

Comment: @mrrogers I wasn't aware I could place them together. Clarification: In this specific order, Concatenate strings and then store result on hidden input field and finally display concatenated result on input field #3.

Comment: Am I correct that you are simply trying to periodically take the input value from "input", concatenate it with the "hidden thing" (which doesn't change) and show and submit that to the backend with ajax?  If so, I'll add an answer with some proper code that should do that.  If I'm misunderstanding the goal, let me know.

Comment: @mrrogers yes correct and also display result on input field 3.

Comment: And the reason for the Ajax, is simply to log that things have been changing?

Comment: @mrrogers yes correct, to log changes.

Comment: I added another possible answer that may solve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is really a revamp of your code, but maybe it will do what you need and simplify things.

If you simply throw out the second input box, and show #result (make it not hidden), i think this code might work to get what you need accomplished, and simplify things a bit.

What this should do is submit a request to the server no more frequently than every 40ms and on success of that request, we update the display value of #result.

I'm now noticing that if this does actually solve the issue, then you've gotten away from the `onChange` issue completely, because the real trigger now is the `keyup` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /** get the inputs we might need */
  var $result = $('#result');
  var $input = $('#input');

  $result.data('url', $result.val());
  var timer;

  /** function to submit data to the server and
      update the result input on success */
  function submitForm( input, newValue) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/concatenate/index.php",
      data: {input:input},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (data) {
        $result.val(newValue);
      }
    });
  };

  /** on key up, fill #result with the url + input */
  $input.bind('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inp = $this.val();
    var url = $result.data('url');
    var newValue = url + inp + '/';

    if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      submitForm(inp, newValue) ;
    }, 40);
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: +1 Okay its working! would it be possible to make an ajax api `GET` request from the input in field 2 in the same function?

Comment: I'm not sure if follow exactly.  But if the other input field is something that folks can type in, then you could do another bind on keyup on $result, and basically run the same thing.  If you go that route, you may want to use another timer variable (timer2) so that you don't clear timeouts from the first timer when stuff happens on the second input.

Answer (score 0):

The OnChange event is not fired when the contents of the field is changed programmatically.  The OnChange event is only raised when a user enters data into the field.

That's just the way this works.